# QWebEngineView inside QGraphicsView (Qt-5.7)

Tags: c++, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to render a QWebEngineView inside a QGraphicsView. It works with a **QGraphicsProxyWidget** but the QGraphicsView is not repainted when the image displayed by the proxied QWebEngineView changes.

Does anyone have an idea of a way to get the QGraphicsProxyWidget to automatically repaint itself when the content of the QWebEngineView changes?

Comment: Please post your code.  Thx